# PDF-files on server will not open when link is clicked in browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, pdf

I've got a pdf on the network server that I'd like to view it in my browser. I do NOT want to download the pdf to view it.

I have the following link:

```
<a href="file://///SERVER/directory/my_file.pdf" target="_blank">Click me!</a>
```

It works and opens perfectly in Chrome, yay! (although it seems like it's only working when I'm logged on using my google-account)

When I click the link in Firefox, nothing happens, less yay...
If I, in Firefox, right-click the link, choose "Copy Link Location" and paste the link into the address field, it opens the pdf just fine.

I've tried using zero and up to 6 of those pesky / after file: just for making sure... I was desperate...

The plug-in for Acrobat Reader is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this not working is because of the security feature not allowing cross-usage of the protocols http:// and file://.

To solve this in **Chrome**, download a plugin called LocalLinks ([link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida/related)).

For **Firefox**, there is currently no solution afaik.

For **Safari** (versions 6+), you could possibly activate the Develop-menu for safari (open preferences, choose advanced and then check the box for "Show develop menu in menu bar") and then enable the option "Disable Local File Restriction". However, this is an untested solution.